# Android Include at the bottom of layout

Tags: android, include, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to attach a layout to the bottom of every activity like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/bottom_Menu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_menu" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

However, it doesn't put it at the bottom.

----EDIT-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/scheduleToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/SchedueToggle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/exhibitorsToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/exhibitorsToggle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/speakersToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/speakersToggle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/MapsToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MapsToggle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/OtherToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/OtherToggle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where does it put it? What does`bottom_menu.xml` look like?

Comment: Why are you aligning it to left and right at the same time? Pick one or center.

Comment: @VM that hooks it to the right and left side making it full width.

Comment: I don't think it's how it works. If you want it's width to be full screen specify layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @codeMagic theres the menu in the post now

Comment: @VM i believe they both accomplish the same result. Either way, it works my way and your way but does not accomplish what i originally asked for help with.

Comment: Have you tried putting the height and width in the `<include>` tag? I don't remember the difference without looking it up but I believe there are some depending on if you have that or not.

Comment: @codeMagic I just got it to work by wrapping it in another layout...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it in the layout, the include needs to have layout_width and layout_height specified for other layout_* fields to work. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html):

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the 
>   tag, you must
>   override both android:layout_height and android:layout_width in order
>   for other layout attributes to take effect.

So your updated layout:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/bottom_Menu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/bottom_menu" />
```

Comment: this included layout floats on keyboard. any solution on that? @VM4